# The included URLconf '<rest_framework.routers.DefaultRouter object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

This is my app route

```
from .views import StudentView
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('student', StudentView)
```

and this is my project URLs file and I am trying to include the Student route in it

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from student_school.urls import router

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'', include(router))
]
```

But am getting this error

**django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<rest_framework.routers.DefaultRouter object at 0x7fddc2abb520>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.**

Comment: You need to include router.urls, not just the router. `path(r'', include(router.urls))` https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#using-include-with-routers

Comment: Got it thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just make this changes.

```
path(r'', include(router.urls))
```

Hope it helps.